# Wp_mail Returning False on Server

Tags: forms, wp-mail

I'm spent the last hour trying to figure out why the wp_mail function is returning a false boolean.

Here's my code.  I can usually get this to work but can't seem to figure it out now.  I'm thinking this has something to do with my server settings.

Thanks for the help.

```
<?php

  $mail ='';
  $errors = '';

  if(isset($_REQUEST['contact_submit'])) {
    $contact_name = $_REQUEST['contact_name'];
    $contact_email = $_REQUEST['contact_email'];
    $contact_subject = $_REQUEST['contact_subject'];
    $contact_message = $_REQUEST['contact_message'];

    $errors = '';
    // Checking if vars are all filled

    if ( $contact_name != '' && $contact_email != '' && $contact_subject != '' && $contact_message != '' ) {

      $to = 'myemail@goeshere.com';
      $subject = 'Contact Form Submission';
      $body = '<html><body><table>';

      if($contact_name) $body .= '<tr><td><strong>Name: </strong></td><td>'.$contact_name.'</td></tr>';
      if($contact_email) $body .= '<tr><td><strong>Email: </strong></td><td>'.$contact_email.'</td></tr>';
      if($contact_subject) $body .= '<tr><td><strong>Phone Number: </strong></td><td>'.$contact_subject.'</td></tr>';
      if($contact_message) $body .= '<tr><td><strong>Message: </strong></td><td>'.$contact_message.'</td></tr>';

      $body .= '</table></body></html>';
      $headers = 'From: ' . $contact_name . ' <' . $contact_email . '>' . "\r\n";
      $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html' . "\r\n";
      $mail =     wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );
    } else {
      $errors = 'Please fill out all fields';
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks okay to me. Instead check whether email working in other part of the website or not!! Use Postman [SMTP Mailer/Email Log](https://wordpress.org/plugins/postman-smtp/) plugin to configure / test / debug your mail system.

Comment: Any update here?

Comment: I think it had something to do with the headers and namecheap's server setting.  Form works without including the $headers for some reason.

Comment: After further research, namecheap will only allow you to use a "to" email that is registered on their server.